# I'm heavily considering to ask a "why I feel better in X community than in Y" style question. Isn't it too broad?

Tags: discussion, scope

I assume questions like this often come up in the potential audience of this site, as I myself often try deconstructing the good and bad aspects of certain communities I'm involved in.

However, it's quite hard to find out with an outsider view and even then, it may fit more to CogSci.SE, or may not even fit an SE site at all.

What are your views on it?

Comment: If you can generalize the question to be about properties of communities that make newcomers feel more or less welcome/comfortable/engaged/etc, it might fit on [Community Building](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 6):

A huge part of why we feel comfortable or uncomfortable in certain situations has to do with the past. I, for instance, am a little nervous about driving on a couple nearby highways because I had terrible experiences with traffic jams there when I was first learning to drive. In the years since, I've had no problems, and I often forget those early (frightening!) experiences, but when I go down those roads, I always have this feeling in the back of my mind that something is not quite as it should be. Without knowing about the traffic jams I went through, my fears would seem totally irrational.

Humans are weird creatures, and we're not always logical. There's often not a clear thought process - conscious or subconscious - from assumption to action. In short, it be extremely difficult to piece together the reasons for why a person thinks a certain way without knowing exactly how they think and what's happened to them in the past.

I won't speak for [Cognitive Sciences Stack Exchange](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/), because I know little about it. It's certainly worth asking about on their meta site. However, given that we on Interpersonal Skills are probably not going to figure out your thoughts in much detail, I imagine we'd close such a question as Primarily Opinion-Based. There's simply no easy way of knowing.

I assume that my rationale here is partly due to my experience with [Health Stack Exchange](https://health.stackexchange.com/)'s longstanding [policy against personal health questions](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/56/2192). The relevant off-topic close reason there is

> Questions requesting personal medical advice are off-topic here. Nobody here can properly address your health issues. Such questions should be taken to your personal physician who can examine you and access your full medical records. For more information, please see [this meta post](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/56/2192).

Answer (score 3):

To add to [HDE 226868's answer](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/158/57).

To address the part of your question:

> it may fit more to CogSci.SE

[Self help questions are not on topic](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for [CogSci](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/) and if the question was asked in the third person it would be too broad.

Also there can be overlap in scope, so a fit on CogSci wouldn't preclude it from this site - although I do understand this is a discussion about establishing our scope.